# Click Event not working on dynamically created button

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom

I am trying to create an interactive tutorial using an array of objects which contain a text for the current task.

The text creates the task and dynamically attaches a button.

```
let currentTutorialCount = 0;
var tutorial = [{
    text: "Welcome, I'll be your Task Manager and Guide <button class = 
   'button-next'> Got it</button>",
    set: function () {
      $('#info-container').addClass('non-active');
      $('#canvas-container').addClass('non-active');
      $('#info-container-transparent').css('display', 'block');
      $('#canvas-container-transparent').css('display', 'block');
      $('#suggestion').html(this.text);
    }
  },
  {
    text: "Here you can find information about your String and Current 
    State <button class = 'button-next'>Got it</button>",
    set: function () {
      $('#info-container-transparent').css('display', 'none');
      $('#info-container-text').addClass('highlightBorder');
      $('#info-container-buttons-transparent').css('display', 'block');
      $('#suggestion').html(this.text);
    }
  },
  {
    text: "Here you can generate new Random Graphs and Strings <button 
    class = 'button-next'>Got it</button>",
    set: function () {
      $('#info-container-text').removeClass('highlightBorder');
      $('#info-container-buttons').addClass('highlightBorder');
      $('#info-container-buttons-transparent').css('display', 'none');
      $('#info-container-buttons-transparent').css('display', 'block');
      $('#suggestion').html(this.text);
    }
  }
];`
```

When I add the event listener on click on the button the plan is to move to the next task by increasing the currentTutorialCount and call the set function:

```
    $('.button-next').click(() => {
     currentTutorialCount += 1;
     tutorial[currentTutorialCount].set();
    });
```

The DOM structure is as follow:

```
<div id="main-feedback-grid">
  <div id="information">
    <p id="suggestion">Welcome, Make your first transition to the next node</p>
    <button class="answer" value="true">Yes</button>
    <button class="answer" value="false">No</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

My issue is that the click event only works when I click the button for the first time. I assume the reference of the button is lost every time the set() function creates a new one. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Please post full html with the buttons parent.

Comment: Hello, the button is created dynamically inside the text property of the tutorial objects and attached to the #suggestion paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running into the classic issue of binding a click event to an element that is not present at runtime. When your script is being evaluated, the element `.button-next` is not yet present in the DOM, so the click event callback will not be bound to the button.

What you want is to rely on event bubbling: you want to listen on an element that is present at runtime, and see if the click event has bubbled from your dynamically-inserted button up to your static element.

Since the button is actually injected as a child node of `#suggestion`, and `#suggestion` is guaranteed to be present in the DOM at runtime, you can listen to the click event bubbling up to the `#suggestion` element instead:

```
$('#suggestion').on('click', '.button-next', () => {
  currentTutorialCount += 1;
  tutorial[currentTutorialCount].set();
});
```

A helpful tip: always select the **closest possible static DOM element** when binding your event listener. It is strongly discouraged to listen to bubbling evnets on `document` or `body`, because it is expensive (the JS engine has to iterate through all child nodes to find out which one emitted the event).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, I imagined that binding was the issue.

Comment: Do you know why the first click event actually fires ?
The .button-next is not present from the beginning but the event works the first time.

Answer (score -1):

You can use like below:

```
$("body").find(".button-next").on('click', function(){
   // your code here
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
Same result, it only fires once.